# Can´t find visual studio designer in a repo project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019, form-designer

i´m new using visual studio, I´m trying to work in a project using visual Basic in studio 2019, its a Windows form project, when i clone de project from a repo the classes and forms look block, i can edit it but the have this block icon tha i dont understand:

[imgPr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d75X.png)

this seem to not be a big deal, but when i try to use the form designer option in visualStudio i cant use it, and i dont know why, does anyone have a clue about it?

[imgPr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt5b0.png)

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first icon just means that the file has been modified from it's checked-in state. You're working on a project that is under source control.

What's wrong with the designer? Just use the "Open" command to open a file in the windows forms editor. If that doesn't work, what error do you get?

Comment: usually when i open a form solution in visualStudio, if i open the Fomr.Designer.vb (using visual basic)with right click->FormDesigner, it opens automatically the formDesigner that is a "drag elements" tool to design the form, but in this case, i took the base program from a git repository and this option is not even available in the right-click menu.

Comment: I've never tried this with VB, but I assume it's the same as with C#: Make sure your project file declares the subtype. So in the vbproj file you should have entries such as: `<Compile Update="Form.vb"><SubType>UserControl</SubType></Compile>`

Comment: It didn´t work, but thank you!

Comment: Does it work if you create a new project from the examples given?

Comment: Nope, it still does not work.

Comment: Hmm.. Then it may be that you're missing some package from the VS installation. I don't know which one, though.